# Ciphertext sent and ciphertext received do not match

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, bufferedreader

I have two `Socket`s, connected to each other though loopback and being controlled by two synchronous methods running on separate threads to simulate a server-client setup for JUnit testing purposes. The server-side socket has a `BufferedWriter`, the client-side socket has a `BufferedReader`.

The intention is to encrypt a plaintext string using RSA via Java's built-in `Cipher` class, send the resulting ciphertext byte array through the `BufferedWriter`, then read it from the `BufferedReader` and decrypt it back into the plaintext.

```
BufferedWriter bw;
BufferedReader br;
public void send(String plaintext){
    byte[] ciphertext = ... //encrypt plaintext here using Java's Cipher class
    bw.write(new String(ciphertext).toCharArray());
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();
}

public void receive(){
    byte[] ciphertext = br.readLine().getBytes();
}
```

Problem is, the byte array read from the `BufferedReader` does not match the byte array sent to the `BufferedWriter`. I print both to the console then copy-paste them below each other in Notepad for comparison and they do not match; attempting to decrypt the received ciphertext anyway naturally throws an `IllegalBlockSizeException`.

Now, I eventually wised up to the fact that `BufferedReader.readLine()` immediately stops the moment it encounters the byte value for the ASCII linefeed and carriage return characters (0A and 0D), regardless of whether there is an actual linebreak or the received data just happens to contain these bytes due to being encrypted. Yet simply repeating `readLine()` and concatenating the results does not help, since there's no way to know which of the two caused `readLine()` to stop and thus no way to know which one to insert back into the ciphertext. Other than these missing characters messing up the ciphertext's length, it comes through fine.

The next thing I tried was replacing `readLine()` with a `read()` repeated until the actual, deliberate line termination:

```
ciphertext = new byte[0];     //to avoid a NullPointerException down the line
byte[] stream = new byte[0];
while(br.ready()){
    stream = Arrays.copyOf(stream, stream.length + 1);
    stream[stream.length-1] = (byte)(char)br.read();
}
ciphertext = Arrays.copyOf(stream, stream.length - 5);
```

This got the correct length for the ciphertext. Now the problem is that while the whole ciphertext is received, it is full of bit errors. Here's an example, RSA-1024 with no padding used (I want to get this done first before throwing in the padding, since it would throw an exception anyway if left like this).

What was sent through the `BufferedWriter`:
`415EFB8FBBF54FB9BFC31C45E9BEA46035D744D0015E8C7A6B17D967FFCE5F18F5A4311BAC5BB572DA3488EE1DEC8018D611A9197C52B768896EF2FE9CFA0B057D5FE478BD85F13274FF3A59B6821F64A7089B7F470B83C010F263B5753202A7EC443E17617CA1D9516F3C57788A43F14A6FB3202317E9E11F35FF2696CE19EC`

What came out of the `BufferedReader`:
`415E7179BB514F057C021C45E93EA46035D74410015E5A7A6B176E67D9CE5F1851A4311BAC5BB572DA343FEE1D1BAC18D611A9197C52B768306E48635BFA0B057D5FE478DD26443274D93A59B61A1F64A7083A7F470B3F54104863B5753202A71B443E17617CC76E516F3C57786043444A6F42202317E9E11F35D92613CE191B`

As you can see, it's similar but there are discrepancies all over the place. I'm *pretty sure* it's caused by the dual type-casting (since `read()` returns an `int`, which won't implicitly convert into `byte`), but would like a second opinion to confirm and point me towards a possible solution. It might be an encoding issue but I'm baffled where that would happen: the ciphertext's `byte`s get turned into `char`s, sent through, read out as `int`s, typecasted back into `char`s then typecasted back into `byte`s. I mean, if a UTF-16 character gets written onto a buffer then gets read back out as an `int` by the same environment that wrote it onto the buffer in the first place, won't that `int` contain the original character's UTF-16 code? Or would typecasting interpret it as ASCII?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciphertext from modern cryptographic schemes is binary. If you assume that the binary data can be interpreted as characters with some kind of character encoding (ASCII, UTF-8, etc.), then you'll be disappointed. Not all bytes make up valid printable characters. Some control characters are even interpreted in some special way which breaks the ciphertext.

That is why you don't use String-based "streams" (`...Reader` and `...Writer` in Java) and use actual streams (`...InputStream` and `...OutputStream`) instead.

If you really need to use the Writers and Readers, then you need to encode the `byte[]` to a printable form, e.g. with Hex or Base64.

Comment: Hmm... converting byte[] to a hex string? Simple and effective. I'm honestly baffled why that didn't occur to me earlier. I even found a seven year old solution for reversing the conversion, right here on this very site. Thanks for the suggestion.